# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred

Tags: appium

Configured with appium and eclipse in mac.

- Almost set Android_home and java_home in appium configuration
- Set capabilities in selenium
- And set `driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Once run selenium shown exception error as:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 2

In appium server shown as:

> [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 2

Here is the code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


String apkpath="apk/path";
File app=new File(apkpath);

capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","G2AXB711Y044HV6");

capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");

capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");

capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ABC");

capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.ABC.Activity");

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`enter code here`
```

> [W3C]     at ChildProcess.proc.on.code 
>   
>   (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/teen_process/lib/exec.js:94:19)
>
> [W3C]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>
> [W3C]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
>
> [W3C]     at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:380:11)
>
> [W3C]     at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>
> [W3C]     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:596:12)

Please suggest any solution?